# URL validation failed error while accessing Oracle Form

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracleforms

I am developing custom application in Oracle Apps which will call an oracle form named form.fmx

I have put form.fmx in FORM_PATH variable of default.env 
I have created section called vikram in formsweb.cfg
I am accessing as http://prod.txis.com:7406/forms/frmservlet?config=vikram&form=form

And getting this error

URL validation failed. The error could have been caused through the use of the browser's navigation buttons ( the browser Back button or refresh, for example). If the error persists, Please contact system administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with Forms server configuration.
With correct config, it is running fine

Answer (score 0):

Try *one of the following methods* to resolve your issue :

> 1. Goto `Internet Options` >> `Security Tab` >> `Trusted sites` >> `Sites` >>
>          Add this website to the zone.
> 2. Issue `select fnd_profile.value('APPS_MAINTENANCE_MODE') from dual;`
>           to see whether returns the result `NORMAL`, If this is not the case  you're in the maintenance mode, and use : 
>         `sqlplus mySchema/myPassword@$AD_TOP/patch/115/sql/adsetmmd.sql DISABLE`
> 3. Click on ***Lock and Edit***, and then
>
>    - Navigate to `Domain structure` >> `Services` >> `Data sources` Where you should see both `oacore_cluster1` and `forms_cluster1` in
>        the `EBSDataSource` targets.
>    - Assume `forms_cluster1` is missing in the `EBSdatasource` target list, then click on the `EBSDatasource` and then go to the
>        `Targets` section. In this page, check the box for `forms_cluster1`.
>    - Save and Activate the changes and see the following view in you    weblogic screen :
>
>    [image]

Comment: Hi Barbaros,
Thanks for your suggestion but this not solved my problem.
getting the same error again.
Any configuration file I am  missing to configure except formsweb.cfg ?